# MPMoviePlayerController doesn't load my video

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to display a video using MPMoviePlayerController, but I can't manage to make it works.
My video is on my server. So I'm trying to display it this way :

```
-(void) playMovieAtURL: (NSURL*) theURL {
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theURL];
    moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlModeDefault;
    moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [moviePlayer play];
}
```

moviePlayer is a property of my viewController.
The URL given is correct (tested in safari).
My video is a .mov video.

When my function is called, I'm just having a black screen. 
Controls don't appear, and I think that the video doesn't load because in the status bar of the app, the network activity indicator is not displayed.

Any help is welcome.

**EDIT**

I've just noticed that trying to reach the video from the device's safari app result this :[image]

**EDIT 2**

My video is 480 × 850, and MPMoviePlayerController only support video up to 640 x 480.
So it can't be played with this framework.
Do I have to resize my video, or is there another frameworks that I can use to displayed it?
I just need a very simple player...

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way:

```
-(void)playMovieAtURL:: (NSURL*) url
{

    moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                 initWithContentURL:url];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                   selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                   name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                   object:moviePlayer];

    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    [moviePlayer play];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:moviePlayer.view];
}


- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
      removeObserver:self
      name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
      object:player];

    if ([player
        respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
    {
        [player.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now, controls are displayed. But I'm getting an infinite loading... My video is never played, and I still not having any activity indicator in the status bar

Comment: added the play function and bringSubViewToFront.

Comment: I've aded this in playMovieAtURL, but it change nothing. The MPMoviePlayerController view is displayed and the controllers too (preview, play, next) but in the top toolbar, close to the "done" button, is written @"Loading..." with an activity indicator. I'm I missing a framework? a delegate protocol? By the way is it normal that `moviePlayBackDidFinish:` is called just after the MPMoviePlayerController`s view is displayed?

Comment: pls have a look at my edit, I've just tried to reach the video from the safari app of the device.

Answer (score 0):

// you can do like this

```
 -(void)playMovie:(id)sender
 {
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
  @"http://www.xxxx.com/movie.mov"];

_moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
             initWithContentURL:url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
               name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
               object:_moviePlayer];

_moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
_moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
[_moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

}

// The Target-Action Notification Method

```
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
   MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
  removeObserver:self
  name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
  object:player];

if ([player
    respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
{
    [player.view removeFromSuperview];
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is similar to lakesh's one. Can you please look comment?

Comment: Oh ok fine i didn't checked his answer... "My video is never played But I'm getting an infinite loading.... here infinite loading means.. can u explain clearly

Comment: I mean : the MPMoviePlayerController view is displayed and the controllers too (preview, play, next) but in the top toolbar, close to the "done" button, is written @"Loading..." with an activity indicator. But video is never displayed (and maybe never loaded).

Comment: May be it is due to network connection...if your net is very slow also   it will take time to load.

Comment: hmm... not sure, it doesn't work even on the simulator (while it take only about 10s to load from safari)

Comment: otherwise for testing purpose just add webview and directly give video url and check whether it is working r nt u will come to knw

Comment: pls have a look at my edit, I've just tried to reach the video from the safari app of the device.

Comment: did you add #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>?